# Mamba error while creating a new virtual environment: could not open lock file

Tags: python, conda, cartopy, mamba

When I run the following command:

```bash
mamba create --name eco-tech-h2gam-venv regionmask cartopy
```

I get this error:

```bash
Looking for: ['regionmask', 'cartopy']

error    libmamba Could not open lockfile 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\pkgs\cache\cache.lock'
```

Any idea how to overcome it?

**Additional Details**

- OS: Windows 11
- Anaconda 3 base distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lock files can be cleared using the `mamba clean --locks` command. See in the documentation (abridged):

```bash
$ mamba clean -h
# usage: mamba clean [-h] [-a] [-i] [-p] [-t] [-f] [-c [TEMPFILES ...]] [-l] [--json] [-v]
#                    [-q] [-d] [-y] [--locks]
# 
# Removal Targets:
#   --locks               Remove lock files.
```